# How to edit cells on UITableView using XIB, just like Storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, storyboard, xib

I'm running on some glitch or may be functionality lack.

I cannot edit UITableView when using XIB, just like Storyboard does.

There is something i'm missing??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not allow being able to edit cells directly in an XIB. You have to create a separate XIB for the cell and in the table view data source return a cell with that cell subclass

Comment: So basically i cannot define TableView content on XIB??? or you al talking about UIViewCell??

Comment: You can't define the table view cell content or basically anything with a XIB with a table view. You can only put contents and make a cell in its own XIB or using a storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Maximillian is right — so instead of designing your cells in a XIB, I would design it in a storyboard, which then you could link into a larger storyboard with [RBStoryboard](https://github.com/rob-brown/RBStoryboardLink).